# Monthly Return Net of Fees

Tags: backtesting, finance, hedge-fund

How can I calculate the monthly return net of fees if the fee is annual?For example, if every year there is a 20% incentive fee, is there a formula to adjust the return of each month to compensate for the annual fee?

Comment: This is either very basic or unclear. What fee? The return of what?

Comment: $20\%$ fee? annual? Guess you mean $20\%$ of profits above a high water mark?

Comment: Agreed, more information is needed to make this interesting.

Comment: I apologize for the horrible wording. I believe it's an extremely basic question, I'm just not sure what the formula is. So to clarify, if I have the gross monthly returns for let's say 2011 and the annual incentive fee for the hedge fund is 20%, how can I calculate the monthly returns net of this fee? I'm having trouble calculating it due to the problem of compounding returns.

Answer (score 1):

Let Ri be the monthly returns (R1 for Jan, R2 for Feb, etc)

Let Ci the the cumulative returns (C0= 0, C1=R1, C2=R1+R2, etc)

Let AWCi be the above water cumulative return, defined as AWCi=MAX[0,Ci]

In any month, the manager "receives" 0.2*[AWCi-AWC{i-1}] ; I say receives in quotes because this number can be negative.

Then the investor receives the rest of the return i.e. Ri-0.2*[AWCi-AWC{i-1}]

Note: This is the *simplest* approach, there can be additional complications, so best find out the rules used by the particular HF in question.